# Why does bg-dark prevent background-color from being set on a Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to change the `background-color` of the following bootstrap navbar. I have loaded my own CSS file *after* Bootstrap CSS is loaded, so my CSS styles *should* have priority. However, this CSS style is *NOT* applied, *unless* I remove the `bg-dark` class from the `<nav>` tag. Why is this the case? If I am loading my CSS after bootstrap, shouldn't my CSS rules override Bootstrap's?

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the document you'll see that Bootstrap's background color is applied using `!important`, probably due to some cascade challenge they had. We need to add that. However, that's still not enough because we need a selector that's at least as specific as theirs. Here I'm using `.navbar.bg-dark`, but `body .navbar` would also work.

A better solution still would be to create a custom class to extend [Bootstrap's background classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/background/#background-color) and use that, as `.navbar.bg-vivid`. This makes it a little more apparent to your future self and other developers what styling was applied.

```css
.navbar.bg-dark,
.navbar.bg-vivid {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar (original classes)</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark bg-vivid mt-2">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar (cusom background class)</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</nav>
```